# Lentidão no carregamento de imagens ionic 3

Tags: c#, .net, ionic3

Boa tarde,

Desenvolvi um app de venda de produtos e, está funcionando perfeitamente. O meu único problema é quanto ao carregamento das imagens.

Baixei alguns aplicativos de lojas, e as imagens aparecem praticamente instantaneamente e, no meu app leva de 5 a 9 segundos pra carregar.

Estou carregando as imagens da seguinte forma:
- Faço uma chamada à minha API;
- Na API gero a imagem em Base64;
- Retorno da API para o app o Base64 da imagem;

Será que tem alguma forma de carregar as imagens mais rapidamente.

Estou usando Ionic 3 e minha API está em C# .Net.

Comment: Tente redimensionar as imagens se elas estiverem grandes.

Comment: Na API eu redimensiona as imagens, e gero um base 64, mas mesmo assim não carrega instantaneamente.